# Exclamation Mark in the Expire column

Tags: network, vpn

I have a VPN issue and I believe it's just routing, but I've notice that there's an exclamation mark in the expire column on a netstat -nr command:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
192.168.1          10.50.50.31        UGSc            0        0   utun3       
192.168.2          10.50.50.31        UGSc            0        0   utun3       
192.168.3/32       10.50.50.31        UGSc            0        0   utun3       
192.168.3          link#7             UCS             0        0     en7      !
192.168.3.1/32     link#7             UCS             1        0     en7      ! <-- what's this?
```

I know what everything else means, but I can't seem to find any info on what the ! means. Anyone know?

Tia...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/apple-open-source/macos/blame/ea4cd5a06831aca49e33df829d2976d6de5316ec/network_cmds/netstat.tproj/route.c#L375) of macos' netstat, `!` is shown when a route's expire time no longer greater than zero:

```
        if ((expire_time =
            rtm->rtm_rmx.rmx_expire - time((time_t *)0)) > 0)
            printf(" %6d", (int)expire_time);
        else
            printf(" %6s", "!");
```

I assume for some routes it's always the case, others are just being gradually  expiring.